Getting Error deprecated service. Please contact to learn more on migrating to Oauth 2. autodesk,two legged authentication,forge viewer
I am not able to upload the drawing file and not able to open file in forge viewer.
I am using a two-legged authentication API. Please find the code snippet below.
$twoLeggedAuth = new TwoLeggedAuth();
$twoLeggedAuth->setScopes( [ 'bucket:read' ,'data:read','data:write' ] );  
$twoLeggedAuth->fetchToken();

For token generation, I am using a two-legged authentication method
How can I change the above code with a new one?

The reason you got this message is because your clientId application is still using Authentication V1.
Auth V1 is not longer available as of July 22nd, 2024. You will need to migrate the application to Auth V2.
We can allow access to your application until July 31st, 2024. I'm negotiating to extend a bit further but no promises yet.
Please provide a written commitment confirming that you will migrate out of V1 by this date.
Please provide the Application Client ID and a contact email that needs to be added to the allow list.
You will have until July 31st to finish up the migration to Auth V2.
You can refer to: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/migration-guide-oauth2-v1-v2
